# C++: error 'std::string' is private

Tags: c++

So, for class, I have to write a program that simulates a horse race. It's our first major project involving classes. I'm stuck receiving the error mentioned in the subject. Now, I have struggled with pointers since they were introduced, so I have zero doubt this is where my overall problem lies. I've asked my professor for help, but he's not replying to my emails. I've also contacted friends, etc. and no one is getting back to me.

This is my header file (Horse.h):

```
#ifndef HORSE_H
#define HORSE_H
#include <string>

class Horse
{
  private:
    std::string name;
    std::string jockey;
    int maxSpeed;
    int distanceTraveled;
    int racesWon;
  public:
    Horse(std::string, std::string);
    void runOneSecond(int);
    void sendToGate();
    void displayHorse (double);  
};

#endif // HORSE_H
```

Here is my Horse.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Horse.h"
using namespace std;

Horse::Horse(string name, string jockey)
{
  srand (time(NULL));
  int maxSpeed = rand() % 30 + 1;
  distanceTraveled = 0;  
};

void Horse::runOneSecond(int maxSpeed) 
{
  srand (time(NULL));
  distanceTraveled = rand() % maxSpeed;
};

void Horse::sendToGate()
{
  distanceTraveled = 0;  
};

void Horse::displayHorse(double raceDistance)
{
  int percentage;
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHorses; i++)
  {
    cout << "|";

  }
};
```

And here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include "Horse.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double raceDistance = 0;
  int numberOfHorses = 0;
  char choice = 'Y';
  string name;
  string jockey;


  cout << "Enter the number of horses for the race: ";
  cin >> numberOfHorses;
  Horse** horsePtr = new Horse* [numberOfHorses];


// Trouble section.   
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHorses; i++)
  {
    cout << "Fill in the name of the horse: ";
    cin >> horsePtr[i]->name;
    cout << "Fill in the name of the jockey: ";
    cin >> horsePtr[i]->jockey;
  }

  cout << "How long should the race be (in meters): ";
  cin >> raceDistance;

  cout << endl;
  cout << "Start!" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHorses; i++)
  {
    horsePtr[i]->sendToGate();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHorses; i++)
  {
    horsePtr[i]->displayHorse(raceDistance);
  }

  cout << "Show the next second of the race? ";
  cin >> choice;

  while(toupper(choice) == 'Y')
  {
    if (toupper(choice) == 'Y')
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHorses; i++)
      {
        horsePtr[i]->runOneSecond(maxSpeed);
        horsePtr[i]->displayHorse(raceDistance);
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Horse.cpp: In member function ‘void Horse::displayHorse(double)’:
Horse.cpp:29:23: error: ‘numberOfHorses’ was not declared in this scope
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHorses; i++)
                   ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
Horse.h: In function ‘int main()’:
Horse.h:8:17: error: ‘std::string Horse::name’ is private
     std::string name;
                 ^
main.cpp:25:25: error: within this context
     cin >> horsePtr[i]->name;
                         ^
In file included from main_dmj8t6.cpp:4:0:
Horse.h:9:17: error: ‘std::string Horse::jockey’ is private
     std::string jockey;
             ^
main.cpp:27:25: error: within this context
     cin >> horsePtr[i]->jockey;
                         ^
main.cpp:55:35: error: ‘maxSpeed’ was not declared in this scope
         horsePtr[i]->runOneSecond(maxSpeed);
                                   ^
```

Comment: What if the line of the error?

Comment: You should only call `srand` once. Also you may find `std::vector<Horse>` much easier to use than pointers. `cin >> horsePtr[i]->name;` this is incorrect as you haven't allocated any Horse object there yet.

Comment: `i < &numberOfHorses` why are you taking the address of `numberOfHorses`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access a `private` member of a `class`. In your example, your `Horse` class contains 5 `private members`:

```
class Horse
{
  private:
    std::string name;
    std::string jockey;
    int maxSpeed;
    int distanceTraveled;
    int racesWon;
public:
};
```

These `private` members can be accessed within the `Horse` class methods, and by any `friend` classes; however: **nothing** else can access them.

```
int main()
{
// Trouble section.   
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHorses; i++)
  {
    cout << "Fill in the name of the horse: ";
    cin >> horsePtr[i]->name; <--
    cout << "Fill in the name of the jockey: ";
    cin >> horsePtr[i]->jockey; <--
  }
}
```

On the two lines marked, you are attempting to access the `private` members of `Horse` and the compiler won't allow it.

Consider making those variables `public` to `Horse`, or providing setter functions for them:

```
class Horse
{
  private:
    std::string name;
    std::string jockey;
    int maxSpeed;
    int distanceTraveled;
    int racesWon;
public:
    void SetName(std::string s) { name = s; }
    void SetJockey(std::string s) { jockey = s; }
};

int main()
{
    std::string jockeyName;
    std::cout << "Enter a name for the jockey: ";
    std::cin >> jockeyName;
    Horse* h = new Horse;
    h->SetJockey(jockeyName);
}
```

You are providing a `public` constructor for `Horse` that takes two `std::string` though (neither which you are using) so you could just pass the relevant information to the `Horse`:

```
Horse::Horse(std::string n, std::string j) : name(n), jockey(j)
{
     // Other things...
}

int main()
{
    Horse* h = new Horse("Phar Lap", "Jim Pike");
}
```

Note that my two examples are just matching your current code. Your arrays should be replaced by [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and pointers, if **required**, should be replaced by [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) (or `std::shared_ptr`, whichever suits your needs).